# How can create Vue.prototype from component?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

please help , how to create Vue.prototype from component ,

when call this.$authen.check() response this.$store ... is undefined.

how can i append vue global with Vue.extend

thank you.

**Dialog.vue**

```
<template>
</template> 

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AuthenDialog',
  data: () => ({
    state: 0,
  }),

  methods: {
    check() {
      console.log(this.$store) // is undefined
    },
  }

  // when i use this it work!
  /*beforeCreate() {
    Vue.authen = Vue.prototype.$authen = this
  }*/
}
</script>
```

**@/plugins/AuthenDialog.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue' 
import AuthenDialog from './Dialog'
AuthenDialog.install = (Vue, options) => {
    Vue.component(AuthenDialog.name, AuthenDialog)

    Vue.authen = Vue.prototype.$authen = new Vue.extend(AuthenDialog)
}

Vue.use(AuthenDialog)
```

Comment: Did you have activated `Vuex` store? You can try with activating store first.

Comment: other component this.$store is define normally,
this.$store is undefined only use from new Vue.extend()
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a data property as the store on the created hook:

```
{
data: () => ({
    store: null,
  }),

methods: {
    check() {
      console.log(store)
    },
  },

created() {
    this.state = this.$store
  }
}
```

and installing the plugin like this

```
AuthenDialog.install = (Vue, options) => {
   Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$authen', new Vue.extend(AuthenDialog))
}
```